# javascript anonymous function add arguments dynamic

Tags: javascript

I hava a question about javascript  anonymous function.

the origin function:

```
!function (n) {
    return n[0].call(1, 2,3);
}

([function (n, t, i) {alert(1);}, function (t) {}
]);
```

my problem is how do I add new function dynamicly to this anonymous function ' arguments like this

```
!function (n) {
    return n[0].call(1, 2,3);
}

([function (n, t, i) {alert(1);}, function (t) {},function (t) {alert('new function');}

]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to dynamically add a function to an array of functions:

```js
function f(n) {
   return n[2].call(1, 2,3);
}

var functionArray=[
  function (n, t, i) {alert(i);}, 
  function (t) {}

];



var fnew= function (t) {alert('new function');}

functionArray.push(fnew)

f(functionArray);
```

Comment: thanks,but the origin scripts can't be modified because it is on the wibsites

Comment: I want to inject some scripts to add my function to origin scripts

Comment: @user7831558 You cannot "inject" scripts in a function. what you can do is override the function behavior.

Comment: @KarelG  Yes, I have to override the function ,but the function is anonymous function , I don't know how to do

Comment: @user7831558 please edit your question, with more details about that function... (the current example doesn't make much sense)